# Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n (n\ge 3)$ be positive numbers .

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$ \left( \frac{a_1}{a_2+a_3}+\frac{a_2}{a_3+a_4}\right) \left( \frac{a_2}{a_3+a_4}+\frac{a_3}{a_4+a_5}\right) \cdots \left( \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n+a_1}+\frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2}\right) \left( \frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2}+\frac{a_1}{a_2+a_3}\right) \geq 1$$
and
 $$ \left( \frac{a_1}{a_2+a_3}+\frac{a_2}{a_3+a_4}+p\right) \left( \frac{a_2}{a_3+a_4}+\frac{a_3}{a_4+a_5}+p\right) \cdots \left( \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n+a_1}+\frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2}+p\right) \left( \frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2}+\frac{a_1}{a_2+a_3}+p\right) \geq (1+p)^n$$Where $p\geq 0.$

I have proved this for 3 variables $a,b,c>0$

$$ \frac{2b}{c+a}+\frac{2c}{a+b}\ge \frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}$$

$$\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} +p\ge\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{b+c}{a+b}+2p \right)\ge (p+1)\sqrt[2p+2]{\frac{b+c}{c+a}\cdot \frac{b+c}{a+b}}\Rightarrow$$

$$\left( \frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} +p\right)\left(\frac{c}{a+b} +\frac{a}{b+c}+p\right)\left( \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+p\right)\ge (p+1)^3$$
But in case of 4 or more variables this mathod can not be used i think

Comment: Try to use the Holder inequality and your inequality.

Comment: No do this with simpler inequalities...maximum level is C-S inequality. I want to do this in elementary way

Comment: Holder inequality can be proved by C-S inequality. But only use C-S directly is quite hard. Even your second inequality is not true. We know that equality happens when all $a_i$ equals to each other but your second inequality gives $\frac{b+c}{a+c}=p$ when equality happens.